# Google re-Captcha is not completely visible on Mobile Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, recaptcha

In my application i found google recaptcha is not visible properly on mobile view , i am trying to set some css setting but its not fixed for all mobile screen.

**skip** and **verify** button is hide from the screen , i am attaching a screenshot of mobile view. where you will find in the below section of the image, the buttons are missing.

[image]